Change font size => change gVim window size
I wish the gVim window to not resize when I change the font size. Is there any way to achieve this?
More explanation: when I change font size in gVim then the gVim window resize automatically whereas if I change font size in Vim (for example by hitting <c--> and <c-+>) then the terminal window won't resize (the latter is the wanted behavior in gVim as well).

It is difficult if not impossible to achieve perfectly because the window size fit perfectly the number of columns of Vim and when changing the font size there are no integer of columns that fit perfectly.
Here is a very rough attempt of adapting the window size when changing the font size:
function! ChangeFontSize()
  let old_size = substitute(v:option_old, '^.*:h\(\d\+\).*$', '\=submatch(1)', '')
  let new_size = substitute(v:option_new, '^.*:h\(\d\+\).*$', '\=submatch(1)', '')
  let factor = str2float(new_size) / str2float(old_size)
  let &columns = float2nr(round(g:columns / factor))
  let g:columns=&columns
  let &lines = float2nr(round(g:lines / factor))
  let g:lines=&lines
endfunction

autocmd VimEnter * let g:columns=&columns|let g:lines=&lines
autocmd VimResized * let g:columns=&columns|let g:lines=&lines
autocmd OptionSet guifont call ChangeFontSize()

On Windows I had to do something even more complex:
function! ChangeFontSize()
  let old_size = substitute(v:option_old, '^.*:h\(\d\+\).*$', '\=submatch(1)', '')
  let new_size = substitute(v:option_new, '^.*:h\(\d\+\).*$', '\=submatch(1)', '')
  let size2pixel = 36.0/20.0
  let width_factor = str2float(new_size) / str2float(old_size)
  let height_factor = str2float(new_size) / str2float(old_size)
  let &columns = float2nr(round(g:columns / width_factor))
  let g:columns=&columns

  let &lines = float2nr(round(g:lines / height_factor))
  let g:lines=&lines
endfunction

function! GetScreenSize(timer)
  let g:columns=&columns
  let g:lines=&lines
endfunction

autocmd VimEnter * call timer_start(200, 'GetScreenSize', {'repeat' : 1})
autocmd VimResized * call timer_start(200, 'GetScreenSize', {'repeat' : 1})
autocmd OptionSet guifont call ChangeFontSize()

Remark: It seems that the values of &lines and &columns are not correct in the handler of VimEnter and VimResized on Windows.

Thanks. This is a nice workaround though, but I wonder why in case of vim the terminal window won’t resize :)

I have tried it but it didn't work very well. Furthermore, the current regex returned Fira Code 14 and I changed with  matchstr(v:option_old, '\d\+') that works for my use case, but the resizing is not really the best. :)

Thanks for the feedback. I'll adapt the solution for the Linux font names (I'm currently on Windows). I agree with you it is very rough in particular when you make a number of small changes (increase the font size one be one till you reach the target). If that is the problem there is probably a way to get better by guessing what was the original desired size (e.g. using a timer).

I have published another solution that seems to give better result. Let me know if it also works better for you ;-)
